# Firebase website with github actions build failing due to node-sass?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, github-actions, firebase-hosting, node-sass

I've been happily deploying my Vue SPA to Firebase Hosting using the github actions they provide as part of the setup.

All of a sudden those actions are failing and I'm not sure how to fix.

This is my .yml action file:

```
name: Deploy to Firebase Hosting on Main merge
'on':
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  build_and_deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - run: npm ci && npm run build
      - uses: FirebaseExtended/action-hosting-deploy@v0
        with:
          repoToken: '${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}'
          firebaseServiceAccount: '${{ secrets.FIREBASE_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_GUARDIAN_7D5C7 }}'
          channelId: live
          projectId: guardian-7d5c7
```

This is the first few lines of the error:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/myProject/myProject/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: /usr/local/bin/node /home/runner/work/myProject/myProject/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/home/runner/work/myProject/myProject/node_modules/node-sass/build'
```

I've tried npm update, npm audit fix, reinstalling etc. I've also tried adding a node-sass rebuild command to the actions run command.

I believe the github build env is ubuntu.

Comment: node-sass is deprecated now.
I also had lot of issues recently using it and the fastest way to resolve it is by changing to the new library dart-sass. Every thing is explained on the node-sass npm page  : https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Comment: @jeremycastelli thanks so much. swapping those packages out did it.

Comment: great, glad it helps